# NetBeans 8.2: странный баг редактора

Tags: ide, netbeans

Этот баг происходит при работе с большими файлами в NetBeans 8.2. Единственное лекарство - перезапуск IDE. Можно ли его как то нормально вылечить...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Строки частично закрыты прямоугольными треугольниками цвета фона строки.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Строки частично закрыты прямоугольными треугольниками цвета фона строки.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ok